# Sharing Core Data between Network Extension and the containing application (MacOs)

Tags: macos, networkextension

I am attempting to share Core Data between a Network Extension and the containing application on MacOs. The Network Extension and containing application both have the same AppGroup entitlement and I use the following to get the URL for the storage:

```
let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "my-group-name")
```

For the containing application, the resulting URL is of the form:

`/Users/***/Library/Group Containers/my-group-name`

But for the Network Extension, the resulting URL is different:

`/private/var/root/Library/Group Containers/my-group-name`

Both the Network Extension and containing application can access their respective Core Data stores, but, of course, they are not shared since the URLs are different.

What am I missing? How is Core Data supposed to be shared between a Network Extension and the containing application?

And, if it matters, I am creating a DNSProxy type extension.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a shared container can only work between two processes running as the same user. In this case the Network Extension is running as root while the containing app is running as a normal user.

This is why the containing app wants to use `/Users/***/Libary/...` for the data and the Network Extension wants to use `/private/var/root/Library/...`. Not going to be able to share.

The suggested approach is to use an IPC mechanism to communicate between the Network Extension and the containing app.